# Selenium/PhantomJS raises error

Tags: python, selenium, browser, phantomjs

I'm trying to run **PhantomJS** driver in **Python** but I'm getting error. I've read that I should pass the whole path as an argument but it didn't help.

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

# driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\Python_projects\chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe') # this works
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='D:\Python\phantomjs-2.0.0-windows\bin\phantomjs.exe')
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path to script", line 8, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='D:\Python\phantomjs-2.0.0-windows\bin\phantomjs.exe')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\webdriver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\service.py", line 75, in start
    raise WebDriverException("Unable to start phantomjs with ghostdriver.", e)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unable to start phantomjs with ghostdriver.
Screenshot: available via screen
```

Do you know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi the documentation says that the path to the executable should be given - https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver_phantomjs/selenium.webdriver.phantomjs.webdriver.html

Comment: Why not add the directory containing the executable in the system path?

Comment: Can't repro with Selenium 2.44.0 and PhantomJS 2.0.0 on Windows.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make the path in raw string, add 'r':

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'D:\Python\phantomjs-2.0.0-windows\bin\phantomjs.exe')
```

Comment: This worked for me and whilst moving phantomjs.exe to the script folder also works, it seems a lesser solution than actually getting the path to be accepted.

Comment: It also works just to properly escape the backslashes (ie put C:\\...\\... in place of C:\...\... etc etc

Answer (score 10):

For simplicity's sake place the executable in the same directory as your script:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS() # now there's no need for a path
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why it wasn't working even when specifying the correct path... copying phantomjs.exe to my python folder worked.

Comment: this is the answer!

Answer (score 0):

For me none of the above solved the problem; I found the code:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
```

Will only work for root...

Answer (score 0):

For me, this works fine and also don't have to specify path for PhantomJS
You need to install pip install phantomjs-binary binary package using pip

```py
pip install phantomjs-binary
```

it will download a package of approx 60MB.
and contains PhantomJS for windows, mac, and Linux as per the running environment.
after that, you can use it

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from phantomjs_bin import executable_path

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=executable_path)
```