# Can't launch PhantomJS with Python in Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, phantomjs

I'm trying to use PhantomJS with Python in my Windows 7, but is not working!
Here what i tried to do.

First, i installed webdriver. In the following code Firefox opens normally, so  i believe webdrive is correctly installed.

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://seleniumhq.org/')
```

Then, i downloaded PhantomJS from the official website, unpacked it and put it in c:\Phantomjs. Then i added it in Environment Variables.
Here what is in there:

> C:\Phantom\phantomjs-2.0.0-windows\bin

So, when i type "phantomjs" in my terminal, it starts normally. But the following code gives me an error:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS( )
```

Error message:

> Exception ignored in: >
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "c:Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 136, in **del**
>       File "c:Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 124, in stop
>       AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'

And here if i change a little bit the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='C:\Phantom\phantomjs-2.0.0-windows\bin\phantomjs.exe')
```

Error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "c:Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 62, in start
>
> stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
>
> File "c:Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 859, in **init**
>
> restore_signals, start_new_session)
>
> File "c:Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 1112, in _execute_child startupinfo)
>
> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "d:\test.py", line 2, in
>
> browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='C:\Phantom\phantomjs-2.0.0-windows\bin\phantomjs')
>
> File "c:Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 51, in **init** self.service.start( )
>
> File "c:Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 69, in start os.path.basename(self.path),
>
> self.start_error_message)
>
> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'phantomjs' executable needs to be in PATH.
>
> Exception ignored in: del of
>
> >
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "c:Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 136, in **del** self.stop( )
>
> File "c:Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 117, in stop
>
> if self.process is None:
>
> AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process'

How can i fix it?

Comment: `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`. Looks like you have provided an invalid path. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29869757/selenium-phantomjs-raises-error

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the **exe extension** is missing in your **path**.

Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
phantomjs_path = r'C:\Phantom\phantomjs-2.0.0-windows\bin\phantomjs.exe'
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(phantomjs_path)
```

Comment: Thanks! But i'm still getting Exception: `Exception ignored in: <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.phantomjs.service.Service object at 0x01E7F5B0>>  > Traceback (most recent call last): >File "c:Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 136, in __del__ >File "c:Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 124, in stop AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'

Comment: This is another exception :) how are you closing the browser? can you put your full code on github so I can have a look to it? it seems that your are not using **browser.close()** or **browser.quit()** to end your session

Comment: @Amanda If this answer responds to your question, could you accept? If I can help you further, I would be happy to do it :)

Comment: Sorry respond so late. I didn't see your answer. My entire code is that what i posted. Is just a test code. I tried include browser.close() and browser.quit(). whit this last one  i got this message:

Comment: Try to have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31262908/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-close)

Comment: I've read the link and tried the following code: `#driver = webdriver.Firefox( )
phantomjs_path = r'C:\Phantom\phantomjs-2.0.0-windows\bin\phantomjs.exe'
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path = phantomjs_path)
if driver:
 driver.close( )
else:
 print("Could not create driver")`  The output was the same exception as my first exception in my first post. If i uncomment that Fifox line and comment the two lines bellow, Firefox opens, normally. I don't know put new lines in these comments, sorry!

Comment: try to pass the path like it is in the answer edited right now.. it used to work for me. In case it wouldn't, can you copy the error raised by the console so I cab understand better :)

Comment: I tried to pass the path. Here the code:
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path = r'C:\Phantom\phantomjs-2.0.0-windows\bin\phantomjs.exe')
if driver:
    driver.close( )
else:
    print("Error")

Comment: All error message i got is these exceptions. In this last case is:
 
Exception ignored in: <bound method Service. __del__ of
<selenium.webdriver.phantomjs.service.Service object at 0x0229F5B0>>
File "c:Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 136, in __del__
File "c:Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 124, in stop
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'
 
And here, how i call the file in terminal:
c:\Python34\python.exe d:\test.py

Answer (score 0):

1. Provide phantomjs.exe path
   driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('./phantomjs.exe')
2. Upgrade your selenium Version to latest and then try running it